# Error while making a histogram of a big number of integers

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a very big dict of lists of int and I want to make a histogram of it. I used the answer on this post:
[Plot histogram of a large number of integers using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156927/plot-histogram-of-a-large-number-of-integers-using-matplotlib)

which for me turned into:

```
#Plot histogram for dates
dict(sorted(date_frequency.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
values = [list(value) for value in date_frequency.values()]
keys = list(date_frequency.keys())

fig_per_date = plt.figure()
per_date = fig_per_date.add_subplot(111)
counts, bins, patches = per_date.hist(
values, bins = len(keys), normed = False, color = 'g',linewidth=0)
plt.gca().set_xlim(values.min(), values.max())
plt.show()
```

and I get this error:

> ValueError: color kwarg must have one color per data set. 9342 data sets and 1 colors were provided

I cant give it 9342 colors.

Comment: Your input data is a list of lists. It should be a single list (or a NumPy array).

Comment: Aside: this line, `dict(sorted(date_frequency.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))`, does nothing, because the result is not assigned to a variable.

Comment: how can I sort it then based on keys?

Comment: Why do you want to sort a histogram?

Comment: I never said the sorting was incorrect; just that the result is never used.